# Plotting live stream from Kafka-Python (with Plotly)

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, plotly-dash, kafka-python

I am using kafka-python to create a **Kafka consumer** (connected to Kafka producer, broker etc.) in Python that is receiving a live stream of data.

Now I just want to have a **live timeseries plot** of this data.

I found **Plotly** as very nice Python library but it seems like they are only providing some server-based solutions.

**Can I make Plotly work for this offline?
Can you suggest other libraries?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Plotly and matplotlib work offline just fine. I think you're confused that Dash, for example, starts its own Flask server... It'd be no different than a Jupyter notebook. What's the issue you're having when you try to use them?

Comment: Any of the examples for plotting a live stream of time series data were referencing the server-supported version ( https://plot.ly/python/streaming-tutorial/ ). And since I am new to Plotly I was not able to make the connection to "plotly.offline" . I am using Bokeh now, and that was much simpler to get started for me. Thanks anyways

Comment: Alright, basically the problem with Kafka (or any such message queue), is that you need to determine how/when you want to batch the records together such that you aren't overloading the downstream system with one record update at a time.

Comment: I used this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUrhOj3DzYs

Comment: @BobBetter the link to that YouTube video is dead.